# Set the background size to 100% initially but ignore div expansion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some issues with `background-size: auto 100%` inside my `btn-icon` class. What is happening below I know is correct, there are no issues with that. When the button text is squished a new line is created meaning the icon should expand to 100% of its new parent height.

I need to try and change the behaviour of `background-size: auto 100%` so that it **initially** sets its height to 100% of the parent height like it does, but then if it were to expand due to a line break it stays exactly the same size therefore not taking 100% height of the new parent's height.

Neat, perfectly sized icon:

[image]

Ugly icon:

[image]

HTML:

```
<a href="#search">
    <div class="button">
        <div class="btn-icon"></div>
        <div class="btn-text">
            <div class="title">Search</div>
            <div class="subtitle">Search for some things by typing things bla bla bla happy days :></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 5px 0;
    //font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #0099ff;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    padding: 2% 0;
    height: 15%;
}

.btn-icon {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    background: url("../img/icons/menu/search.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-text {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-text .title {
    font-size: 1.05em;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.btn-text .subtitle {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added the JavaScript and jQuery tags to the question as I was unsure if what I'm asking can be completed with CSS alone

Comment: Why don't you set the background-size to a static value?

Comment: @alberto2000 Good question, because then the size of the icon wouldn't be relative to the size of the button. The point of this question is to help to maintain a fluid design, if I were to set it to a static value it would no longer be relative to the button (as the button size is a percentage)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, at upstart, calculate icon height to be 100%, and when you add that dynamic text to search div, just make icon in center (`margin-top: 50%, top: -$('#icon').height()/2 + 'px'`